# Displaying and editing data by XY-plot

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, 3d, plot

I have a mapping between 16 fixed numbers (points on the X axix) and their values (displayed on the Y axis). What I need is to display this data as XY-plot and to be able to change those values by moving selected point up or down. it should look something like:
[image]

What are possible approaches to implement this functionality (in winforms or wpf)? Maybe there are some third-party libraries which already implements most of it.

Also, there is a possible situation when fixed numbers contains two coordinates (placed in the square). In that case, a 3D-plot will be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can strongly recommend the Microsoft WinForms Chart Controls
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418
Download the sample Poject, have a look at

Chart Features -> Interactive Charting -> Changing Values by...

The Winform Chart is just awesome as well as the provided Samples Environment!